# Put Ubuntu Touch on Samsung GS3?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, samsung

I saw that Ubuntu Touch has been released and am wondering what the steps are in order to put it onto my Samsung Galaxy S3.  I currently have an un-rooted GS3 running Jellybean and would love to get Ubuntu on it (especially if they can run side-by-side).

If anybody can help walk me through it, I'd be grateful.  If there's a walkthrough somewhere online which I haven't been able to find yet, I'd be appreciative to get a link too.

Thank you very much!

Comment: It seems that there has been some work on it: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/02/ubuntu-phone-up-running-on-samsung-galaxy-s3

Answer (score 2):

If you look you'll see that the RIL is not working listed as broke/not working.  Which means you will have no phone functionality.  Give it some time.  It's a bit early.  There was a write up about touch 1.0 on a nexus device.  Looks great but there are some real probems still.
Patience is a virtual.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the status of all devices here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices

As stated there for SGS III. It's not yet working but there is at least a contact. If you want you can contact him and check if there is anything you can help him with.

Comment: I never found that page.  So thanks a bunch.  I'll keep waiting patiently :)